# Get mouse pointer without connecting usb mouse in android

Tags: android, mouseevent, mousemove

hi i am writing an application where i am sending the mouse movements to server from my client 
application via wifi using http.Here my client application runs in my smartphone and my server runs in a  smart stick where i can connect this stick to  monitor.The server os is android.I want to control the the mose movements from my smart phone  like i want to use my smart phone as mouse.
The problem is  i am getting the mouse movements  and i can send it to the server.For the mouse cursor i know i can get it by connecting a usb mouse but i want to know is there any way to get the mouse pointer without connecting the usb mouse.

Thanks for any help..

Comment: What is the OS in the smart stick?

Comment: server runs android os